# Can iOS framework generated by Xcode 6 be used in previous versions of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

Before June 2 2014 Xcode can only generate a static library for iOS. While they announced that  iOS can also support creating framework. My question is, is the newly generated iOS frameworks be used in previous versions of Xcode or iOS?